# Should I use elif if I have already returned from the function in a previous block?

Tags: python, coding-style

```
def size(number):
    if number<100:
        return Small()

    if number<1000:
        return Medium()

    return Big()

def size1(number):
    if number<100:
        return Small()
    elif number<1000:
        return Medium()
    else:
        return Big()
```

Regarding coding style:
I often use the former when the following blocks, or the last block is a large chunk of code. It seems to help readability.

I generally use the latter when the various blocks have a common concept running through them (as in the case above). The common indentation helps to communicate their relationship.

Are there any differences between these two worth noting (esp. performance wise)?

Comment: the second example is more readable imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Style-wise, I find the second example easier on the eye.

In all other respects, there is no difference. The two functions compile to identical bytecodes:

```
In [3]: dis.dis(size)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
              6 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       19

  3          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Small)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 RETURN_VALUE        

  5     >>   19 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1000)
             25 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       38

  6          31 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Medium)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             37 RETURN_VALUE        

  8     >>   38 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (Big)
             41 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             44 RETURN_VALUE        

In [4]: dis.dis(size1)
 11           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
              6 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       19

 12          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Small)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 RETURN_VALUE        

 13     >>   19 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1000)
             25 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       38

 14          31 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Medium)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             37 RETURN_VALUE        

 16     >>   38 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (Big)
             41 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             44 RETURN_VALUE        
             45 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             48 RETURN_VALUE
```

(To be 100% accurate, the second version has an implicit `return None` at the end. However, since this code is not reachable, it won't affect performance.)

Answer (score 0):

You can only know about the performance for a specific case by benchmarking/timing it (or as @aix shows, looking at the translated code, assuming the code segment is sufficiently small).

Having said that, I think the *semantics* of the 2nd example are clearer since the language construct shows that the options are mutually exclusive.

In general, given the same functionality, an `if/elif/else` clause should be more efficient than a series of `if`-statement where multiple `if` statements may be executed/evaluated in sequence even if a previous `if` has been found to be true. In this specific code example this is not the case since there is a `return` executed as soon as the appropriate body of the `if` statement is executed.